# Googleグループ（メーリングリスト）の「件名のプレフィックス 」の項目に関して

Tags: google-groups

[https://groups.google.com/a/[ドメイン名]/forum/#!groupsettings/[グループ名]/email](https://groups.google.com/a/[%E3%83%89%E3%83%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E5%90%8D]/forum/#!groupsettings/[%E3%82%B0%E3%83%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%97%E5%90%8D]/email)
上記URLから設定できる「件名のプレフィックス」に通し番号を付与しようと思い
[グループ名:%d]
というふうに設定を行っているのですが、常に
[グループ名:0]
という件名が付く状態となってしまいます。
メールが送られる度に数字が増えることを期待しているのですが、なにか別の設定が必要なのでしょうか？

なお、実際は「グループ名」の部分は半角文字です。
設定に当たり
https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1701/13/news033.html
こちらのURLなどを参考にしております。
よろしくお願いいたします

Comment: アーカイブ ON になっていますでしょうか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
アーカイブはONになっていない状態となっております。

Comment: では、アーカイブ ON にして試してみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。先程試したところ、正常にカウントアップしていることが確認できました。非常に助かりました。ありがとうございました

Answer (score 1):

アーカイブ ON にして試してみてください。

<sub>-- この回答は [Taichi Yanagiya](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/4603/taichi-yanagiya) さんの[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/54050/google%E3%82%B0%E3%83%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%97-%E3%83%A1%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AA%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88-%E3%81%AE-%E4%BB%B6%E5%90%8D%E3%81%AE%E3%83%97%E3%83%AC%E3%83%95%E3%82%A3%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B9-%E3%81%AE%E9%A0%85%E7%9B%AE%E3%81%AB%E9%96%A2%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6#comment56868_54050)をコミュニティ wiki として投稿するものです。</sub>