# Googleグループ（メーリングリスト）の「件名のプレフィックス 」

Tags: google-groups

他の方が質問されている内容ですが、私は解決しないのでお知恵を貸してください

[Googleグループ（メーリングリスト）の「件名のプレフィックス 」の項目に関して](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/54050)

こちらでは[グループ名:%d]といれても表示されません。
アーカイブをONにしようとしましたが、チェックがグレー表示になってできません。

[image: スクリーンショット]